# Changing the background image based on time of day

Tags: jquery, css

I have a "section" that has a background image with it.

```
<section id="header" class="color-light text-center" data-type="background" data-speed="10">
```

this is the CSS

```
#header {
   background: url('sunrise.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
   height: 800px;
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   color: #f4f4f4;
 }
```

Using this javascript that i check the time of day...

```
      var d = new Date();
      var n = d.getHours();
      if (n > 19 || n < 6)
        $("#header").className = "night";
      else if (n > 16 && n < 19)
        $("#header").className = "sunset";
      else
        $("#header").className = "day";
```

I have this in the css file....  but not sure how or if i need to use it

```
/* backgrounds */
.day { background: url('sunrise.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed; }
.sunset { background: url('sunset.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed; }
.night { background: url('night.jpg')50% 0 no-repeat fixed; }
```

I am not sure if i am missing the way to change the #header using jquery, and apply the updated background value.

Comment: Off topic but, #header is day when n=16 and n=19 then? You'll need to add logic for that.

Comment: You should simply use `background-image` so you don't set the other properties everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be all you need to do to make it work

```
var d = new Date();
      var n = d.getHours();
      if (n > 19 || n < 6)
        $("#header").css("background", "url('night.jpg')");
      else if (n > 16 && n < 19)
        $("#header").css("background", "url('sunset.jpg')");
      else
        $("#header").css("background", "url('day.jpg')");
```

Answer (score 2):

`className` is not a property you can access through the jQuery object directly.  To change a property on a jQuery object, you can use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), but in this case because it's a class, you can simply use `.addClass()`, `.removeClass()`, and `.toggleClass()`. See here: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/

Provided there are no other issues with the code, this should work:

```
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getHours();
  if (n > 19 || n < 6)
    $("#header").addClass("night");
  else if (n > 16 && n < 19)
    $("#header").addClass("sunset");
  else
    $("#header").addClass("day");
```

Comment: Is there any good way to make the background change after page load? I.e. with a timeout?